# Changing the norm will affect a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-fixed-point, contraction-operator

Say I have a $\beta$-contraction $T$, e.g., $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|| T(x) - T(y)|| < \beta ||x-y||$, $\beta <1$. Now, suppose I want to work with another norm $\|  \|_{2}$. Under this norm, will $T$ still be a contraction? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, it might not be a contraction.  A sufficient condition for it to be a contraction would be $$\alpha \| \cdot \|_2 \le \| \cdot \| \le \gamma \|\cdot\|_2$$ where $\beta \gamma < \alpha$.

Comment: Thanks! That's right, I was using exactly this reasoning to justify the fact that this might not be always the case.